# CORS Filter before Authentication Filter - is less secure? Spring Security Filter Chain Order

Tags: angularjs, spring, security, cors

I found that while accessing ReST services from single-page applications that in order to properly allow access to ReST endpoints I had to register a CORS filter before my authentication filter. Is this less secure or a poor security practice?

My security configuration now looks like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Inject
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
           .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/health","/metrics", "/v1/users/register", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v2/api-docs").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/mappings", "/v1/**", "/backend-service/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .realmName("serviceGateway")
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
            .and().addFilterBefore(new SimpleCORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    }

}
```

And my SimpleCORSFilter looks like

```
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    /**
     * This method adds specific headers to the HTTP request to enable CORS
     * requests
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @param chain
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws ServletException
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, x-requested-with, Cache-Control");
        chain.doFilter(request, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

I access the code with a simple $http call in Angular

```
$scope.login = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://myservice.mydomain.com:8095/v1/users/login',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("username:password")
    }
  })
    .then(successCallback);
};
```

I am thinking that putting the CORS filter before security only means that the CORS headers will be added to every request, which doesn't seem like much of a security hole since I send no sensitive data in headers, excepting the Authorization header.

Am I thinking right here or is there something I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is perfectly fine. In fact when your JavaScript code posts to a resource in another origin, the browser will issue a pre-flight request (`OPTIONS` verb) without the `authorization` header.

If your authentication code runs before the CORS handler, it has to make an exception for this request, to avoid returning `401 Unauthorized` on the pre-flight.

Answer (score 0):

In preflight options request, from browser we never get auth token, hence cors filter added before checking authentication should be fine